# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty f(x)\sin(x)\mathrm dx$

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals

My task is : $ f : [0, \infty[  \to [0, \infty[$, 
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) =0$

How can I show that this improper integral converges:
$ \int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(x) \, dx$?

Is it right that this integral converges to $0$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need some more conditions on $f$ to conclude that the integral converges. Is $f$ monotonic?

Comment: Oh !! yes it is monotonically decreasing...hmm sorry i missed that totally

Comment: See Dirichlet's test for integrals.

Comment: If it is monotonically decreasing, $\int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(x)\; dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1 f(x+n\pi) \sin(x)\; dx$ is an alternating series.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n=\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}f(x)\sin(x)dx$, so we want to prove $\sum_0^\infty a_n$ converges. Note that since $f$ is non-negative and monotonically decreasing, while $\sin$ alternates sign, $a_n$ has the same sign as $(-1)^n$ and $|a_n|$ is monotonically decreasing.
Therefore by alternating series test $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\sin(x)dx=\sum_0^\infty a_n=\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n|a_n|$$ converges.